# Regadring program on concurrent HashMap

Tags: java, collections

In an interview, the interviwer asked about concurrent Hash Map and it functionality, which I explained in detail.  He said that, in case of a concurrent HashMap update operation, ConcurrentHashMap only locks a portion of the Map instead of the whole Map.

So he told me to write a simple program that proves that, during the update operation, ConcurrentHashMap only locks a portion of Map instead of whole Map.  I could not able to this, so please advise me how to achieve this.

Comment: What behavior would you expect to see if the entire map was locked during updates versus not?

Comment: A quick 'naive' guess is that it just locks the relevant 'bucket', however that's implemented.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't believe that you can *prove* this behavior using just the public API.

Comment: Given that the details of the internal partitioning are unspecified, this is going to be a tough one to "prove".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interviewer was possibly expecting a simple answer, such as:

- if the whole map is synchronized for get/put operations, adding threads won't improve throughput because the bottleneck will be the synchronized blocks. You can then write a piece of code with a synchronizedMap that shows that adding threads does not help
- because the map uses several locks, and assuming you have more than one core on your machine, adding threads will improve throughput

The example below outputs the following:

> Synchronized one thread: 30
>   Synchronized multiple threads: 96
>   Concurrent one thread: 219
>   Concurrent multiple threads: 142

So you can see that the synchronized version is more than 3 times slower under high contention (16 threads) whereas the concurrent version is almost twice as fast with multiple threads as with a single thread.

It is also interesting to note that the ConcurrentMap has a non-negligible overhead in a single threaded situation.

This is a very contrived example, with all the possible problems due to micro-benchmarking (first results should be discarded anyway). But it gives a hint at what happens.

```
public class Test1 {
    static final int SIZE = 1000000;
    static final int THREADS = 16;
    static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Concurrent one thread");
            addSingleThread(new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> ());
            System.out.println("Concurrent multiple threads");
            addMultipleThreads(new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> ());
            System.out.println("Synchronized one thread");
            addSingleThread(Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, Integer> ()));
            System.out.println("Synchronized multiple threads");
            addMultipleThreads(Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, Integer> ()));
        }   
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private static void addSingleThread(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            map.put(i, i);
        }
        System.out.println(map.size()); //use the result
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("time with single thread: " + (end - start) / 1000000);
    }

    private static void addMultipleThreads(final Map<Integer, Integer> map) throws Exception {
        List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
            final int start = i;
            runnables.add(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Trying to have one runnable by bucket
                    for (int j = start; j < SIZE; j += THREADS) {
                        map.put(j, j);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<> ();
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (Runnable r : runnables) {
            futures.add(executor.submit(r));
        }
        for (Future f : futures) {
            f.get();
        }
        System.out.println(map.size()); //use the result
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("time with multiple threads: " + (end - start) / 1000000);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , perfect explnation could you once more please explain the above program in brief I have understood it partially, pleasea explain one more Thanks in advance.

Comment: the two methods simply add 1 million entries to the map. the first one is run in the main thread, the second one is run with an executor service that has 16 threads. To try make to help the CHM, I count with a step of 16 (so one thread will put 0, 15, 31 etc, the second thread 1, 16, 32 etc) which should reduce lock contention and associate each thread with one lock (there are 16 locks, based on the hashcode of the key modulo 16). Note that the effect is more pronounced with more threads (with 100 threads, the sychronized version really suffers).